# Can't find out radiobutton click events in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working with 2+2 radiobutton in my application. when i click any radio button it will affect on some input fields. But i am confused about to using click event with jquery.i already searched on stack overflow .there are so many suggestion and i'm confused after seeing so many suggestion.i tried some of them but not worked .
This is my HTML Code

```
<input type="radio" id="voucher" name="voucher" value="1"
        checked="checked">Payment Voucher <input type="radio"
        name="voucher" id="voucher" value="2">Receive Voucher

     <input type="radio" name="transaction" id="transaction"
                                        value="1" checked="checked">Cash <input type="radio" name="transaction" id="transaction" value="2">Bank
```

And i tried this jquery code :

```
$("input").on( "click", function() {
    if ($("input:radio[name=voucher]").is(":checked")) {
        check = $('input:radio[name=voucher]:checked').val();
        alert(check);
        if (check == 1) {

            $("#credit").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#debit").prop("disabled", false);
        } else if (check == 2) {

            $("#debit").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#credit").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    }
});

$("#transaction").click(function(event) {
    if ($("input:radio[name=transaction]").is(":checked")) {
        checktransaction = $('input[name=transaction]:checked').val();

        if (checktransaction == 1) {

            $("#bankacc").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#chequeno").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#cashinhand").prop("disabled", false);
        }

        if (checktransaction == 2) {

            $("#cashinhand").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#bankacc").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#chequeno").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    }
});
```

This is the snippet:

```js
    $("input").on( "click", function() {
        if ($("input:radio[name=voucher]").is(":checked")) {
            check = $('input:radio[name=voucher]:checked').val();
            alert(check);
            if (check == 1) {

                $("#credit").prop("disabled", true);
                $("#debit").prop("disabled", false);
            } else if (check == 2) {

                $("#debit").prop("disabled", true);
                $("#credit").prop("disabled", false);
            }
        }
    });

    $("#transaction").click(function(event) {
        if ($("input:radio[name=transaction]").is(":checked")) {
            checktransaction = $('input[name=transaction]:checked').val();

            if (checktransaction == 1) {

                $("#bankacc").prop("disabled", true);
                $("#chequeno").prop("disabled", true);
                $("#cashinhand").prop("disabled", false);
            }

            if (checktransaction == 2) {

                $("#cashinhand").prop("disabled", true);
                $("#bankacc").prop("disabled", false);
                $("#chequeno").prop("disabled", false);
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="voucher" name="voucher" value="1"
     checked="checked">Payment Voucher <input type="radio"
     name="voucher" id="voucher" value="2">Receive Voucher
                      
     <input type="radio" name="transaction" id="transaction"
             value="1" checked="checked">Cash <input type="radio" name="transaction" id="transaction" value="2">Bank
```

Comment: There was a error in your code. I don't really understand what you want to do?

Comment: What are all those elements where you toggle the disabled attribute? And what exactly does it have to do with having two pairs of radio? And you're using ID's multiple times. This is not correct in any way.

Comment: i actually just  want to know which radio button click event i have to use . sorry for wrong code . i just keep the main portion of my code thats why there was some error .

Comment: What problem are facing actually ?

Comment: @MoshiurRahman If I am not wrong you want to detect which radio button is actually selected/changed.

Comment: i have 14 input element and  that's why i ignored these . do i need to edit and give the full code ?

Comment: @VivekSingh yes .you are right . actually want to know the basic click event to detect these radio button . and then i may take some action based on click.

Comment: Code works but you want to find out if 'click' if a good enough event? My suggestion - use 'change'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change id to class (id is unique) and capture the event to get the target. See snippet:
Hope it helps.
Regards

```js
$(".voucher").on( "click", function(event) {
          var target = $( event.target );
        if (target.is(":checked")) {
            check = target.val();
            alert(check);
            if (check == 1) {

                $("#credit").prop("disabled", true);
                $("#debit").prop("disabled", false);
            } else if (check == 2) {

                $("#debit").prop("disabled", true);
                $("#credit").prop("disabled", false);
            }
        }
    });

    $(".transaction").click(function(event) {
     var target = $( event.target );
        if (target.is(":checked")) {
            checktransaction = target.val();
            alert(checktransaction);
            if (checktransaction == 1) {

                $("#bankacc").prop("disabled", true);
                $("#chequeno").prop("disabled", true);
                $("#cashinhand").prop("disabled", false);
            }

            if (checktransaction == 2) {

                $("#cashinhand").prop("disabled", true);
                $("#bankacc").prop("disabled", false);
                $("#chequeno").prop("disabled", false);
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" class="voucher" name="voucher" value="1"
     checked="checked">Payment Voucher <input type="radio"
     name="voucher" class="voucher" value="2">Receive Voucher
                      
     <input type="radio" name="transaction" class="transaction"
             value="1" checked="checked">Cash <input type="radio" name="transaction" class="transaction" value="2">Bank
```

Comment: Thanks . It works.  i checked one of the radio button . when i reload it didn't show 1 is checked . how to solve this problem ?

Comment: You could use an unique id to get the initial value..regards

Comment: can you please explain it in more detail please ?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use the Change Function to get the value of the checked radio buttons  like below code

```
$('input[name="voucher"]') 
.change(function(){ 
    if( $(this).is(":checked") ){ 
        var val = $(this).val(); 
        //alert(val)

        if (val == 1) {

        $("#credit").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#debit").prop("disabled", false);
    } else if (val == 2) {

        $("#debit").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#credit").prop("disabled", false);
    }

    }
});


 $('input[name="transaction"]') 
.change(function(){ 
    if( $(this).is(":checked") ){ 
        var val = $(this).val(); 
      if (val == 1) {

            $("#bankacc").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#chequeno").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#cashinhand").prop("disabled", false);
        }

        if (val == 2) {

            $("#cashinhand").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#bankacc").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#chequeno").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    }
});
```

**I also added a  working fiddle is also added for your help See the fiddle below**

[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/j2Lo0epq/1/)

Comment: Thanks . It works. i checked one of the radio button . when i reload this page it didn't show  first what i did for the checked radio buttons, after again check it works. how to solve this problem ?